# Connection Failed SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

I have the following code snippet:

```
SqlConnection sr = new SqlConnection(this.strConnection);
sr.Open();
```

Where connection string is:

```
Data Source = localhost;Initial Catalog=UIB_IS;Persist Security info=True;User ID=USR;Password=PSW;
```

(I have removed the user name and password from above for purpose of this question - I have double checked the password has not expired and is still the same.)

Every time I try to open the connection I get a failed exception.

I have also tried using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server()` object with a string connection as well as a `ServerConnection` object. With the server connection object using a string and `SQLConnection` object.

None seem to be working.

Within the connection string I have tried the syntax `ServerName\SQLSERVERNAME`, `127.0.0.1` as well as `localhost` as you can see above.

Previously this code has been working over the last 6 months using the `'ServerName\SQSERVERNAME'` syntax in the connection string on a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server()` object.

This last week.....no longer works.

No System updates have been applied. The DB and SQL User exist with the appropriate permissions set as were before. SQL Server still has allow remote connections set to allow.

The server firewall is also off (Development machine)

I cannot understand why it would suddenly stop working?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exact error does it show?

Comment: 'Request Failed' System.Security.SecurityException

Comment: Are you logged in with a different user, or a different domain or something when testing it?

Comment: Additional INformation: Machine and web.config are set to Full.

Comment: No, Logging in as the same user previously used. Same domain and no domain changes recently either.

Comment: Additional Information: No System event logs are being wrote out either.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your Sql Server allow remote connections.  You can check its status under Sql Server Surface Area Configuration -->  Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connection.

Comment: sorry i should of mentioned im using SQL Server 2008. So no Surface Area Confiuration tool. However when going via 'Facets' and under menu 'Surface Area Configuration'  there is nothing related to remote connection stated. However if you read in above you will notice i already checked allow remote connections is still set. Which it is. Thanks anyway.